# How to compare two elastcsearch cluster document count

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two elasticsearch cluster.Cluster one and two has same index.
eg : cluster two is create with cluster one snapshot.I need to verify cluster one and two has same indexes and same documents count.How to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i wrote the script for this one.You can download this python script and you can generate simple report.It may request python elasticsearch library and urllib3.Please verify this two library is already installed.I will update README.md file how to run this script.

[Elasticsearch compare (Git repo)](https://github.com/warunaeniplex/compare_two_elasticsearch.git)

MATCH COUNT

abc: Document count 52 : 52

def: Document count 235 : 235

MISSED MATCH COUNT

test_abc: Document count    8820 : 8823

test_abc: Document count    5688 : 5683

ERRORS

customer_index
user_index